# How slicing inequality interval by numpy or scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have numpy 2d array `A = [[1,1,1,1,1],[1,2,3,4,5]]`

I want a function(A,B,axis) to assign interval,which results

```
([[1,1],[1,2]],[[1,1,1],[2,3,4]],[[1,1],[4,5]])
```

, effectively with interval position `B=[0,1,3,4]` and `axis=0`.In additional,it'll be better that lazy  assignment each slice matrix like using generator because these matrixes can be very big size.
I know it easily accomplishment by for loop and yield iterator but I don't use loop for performance as possible.

Do you know the best way?

In my thought way,

```
 def assign_interval(A,B,axis):
     if axis == 0:
        for i in range(len(B)-1):
            yield A[:,B[i]:B[i+1]]
     else:
        for i in range(len(B)-1):
            yield A[B[i]:B[i+1],:]
```

**Edit:**

I'm apologize my code didn't work.I was really busy today so that I couldn't inspect above code well and it's with the intention of dummy code for comprehension to process that I want.But,this code make terribly mistakes too much. Now, the code is revised and it'll be fine to work.

`list(assign_interval(A,B,0))`

results

```
[array([[1],
    [1]]), array([[1, 1],
    [2, 3]]), array([[1],
    [4]])]
```

in my environment.

Comment: I am not able to run the func `assign_interval` with the given inputs.

Comment: @Divakar Thanks for pointing out my mistakes. I revised it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use [`np.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) -

```
def assign_interval_split(A,B,axis):
    if axis == 0:
        return np.split(A[:,B[0]:B[-1]],B-B[0],axis=1)[1:-1]
    else:
        return np.split(A[B[0]:B[-1]],B-B[0],axis=0)[1:-1]
```

Comment: It'll be great for my application!  And axis is no need my original enum.So it'll be no need to be function.Your code is very helpful. I really appreciate it!